# Which jQuery needed to use CouchJS?

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I run this code [here](http://pastie.org/4106327)

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>-->

<script>
<!--var dbc = $.jqCouch.connection('db');-->
<!--dbc.exists('database_name');-->

<!--if ($.jqCouch.connection('db').create('database_name').ok) {-->
    <!--alert("database created");-->
<!--}-->

$.couch.activeTasks({
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
</script>

</html>
```

and I get the error. I have tried with all kind of jQueries such as everything with UI -custom and the 1.72 as you can see in the code. So why do I get this error? And where can I find which jQuery is needed to use the CouchJS?

> **Puzzles**
>
> 1. Joy solved the jQuery -problem picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n72AQ.png).
> 2. Now some odd type-error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Ixr.png) and source [here](http://pastie.org/4106383).

**Perhaps useful to other beginners with CouchDB**

1. [Simple example about CouchJS in userspace for example with Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076076/simple-example-about-couchjs-in-browser)
2. [Easy way to tell which JQuery functions are needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914770/easy-way-to-tell-which-jquery-functions-are-needed)
3. [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

Comment: You need to uncomment this line `<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>-->` and load it at the top before `jQuery UI`.

Comment: Based on your setup [this](http://pastie.org/4106353) should remove that error, if it doesn't then check if your path to jQuery is correct or load jQuery from [CDN](http://pastie.org/4106376).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load jQuery before, `jQuery UI` or `Couch JS` because they both uses `$` variable inside those files, and `jQuery.js` defines that `$` as an alias to the `jQuery` object. So `$` has to be defined first before being used. So change your code to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
```

And it should Work fine.

For production websites I would recommend loading jQuery from a CDN( You can do a quick google search to find the benefits of using CDN for jQuery if you dont already know) like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please include jQuery before `jquery.couch.js`.