# Limit jquery file to required functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery. Although I'd like to think of myself as a fairly good programmer in general and also specifically for JS, I don't think I understand the DOM api and its variable behavior in different browsers. Hence the use of jQuery.
I use a small subset of jquery, though: 
1) Ajax
2) event handlers
3) Selectors/find/child/parent

I don't use anything else, no filter, no UI events, nothing! (okay fine slideup slidedown, but I can do that myself using css)

Are there any already existing tools command-line/browser based that would do a static analysis on the jquery script so that I don't have to force the user to download the full 100KB? If you're suggesting I do it myself, thank you, manually doing it would be the next step, and if I feel like there's a lot of interest, I might consider writing such a tool

Re: CDN- thanks for your suggestions, please see my comment to @Jonathan

Comment: have a look at [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)

Comment: What is your target audience? If you want it for a public website please consider that much of your audience will already have a cached version of the common jQuery CDNs, so it will actually load much faster than you using an un-cached subset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extract a subset of jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333465/is-it-possible-to-extract-a-subset-of-jquery)

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you for your comment. However, I'm not very keen on using a CDN. I can't find the link right now which has study about it, but in general, the issue is not b/w- the issue is latency. DNS lookup + HTTP connection. I'm going to concatenate all my js into one js that would include jquery

Comment: @abI Thanks for pointing out. Wouldn't mind if you close this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take each function from [the Github repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), but since there are various dependencies, you will not save as much as you think. Instead of using the 100kb uncompressed, development version, you'll do better using the 32kb minified version from http://jquery.com/download/.

There are also three good reasons to use [jQuery from Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) (`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>`):

> **1. Decreased Latency**
>    In the case of Google’s AJAX Libraries CDN, what this means is that any users not physically near your server will be able to download jQuery faster than if you force them to download it from your arbitrarily located server.
>   **2. Increased parallelism**
>   To avoid needlessly overloading servers, browsers limit the number of connections that can be made simultaneously. Depending on which browser, this limit may be as low as two connections per hostname.
>   **3. Better caching**
>   [W]hen a browser sees references to CDN-hosted copies of jQuery, it understands that all of those references do refer to the exact same file. With all of these CDN references point to exactly the same URLs, the browser can trust that those files truly are identical and won’t waste time re-requesting the file if it’s already cached. Thus, the browser is able to use a single copy that’s cached on-disk, regardless of which site the CDN references appear on.

Source of excerpt *and* further reading: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: Thanks.
I'll have one combined JS file for everything. 
Don't want to separate out jQuery beacuse DNS lookup + HTTP connection to google servers would take extra time too.

1) Latency: I win
2) Parallelism: I win
3) I've read a study which showed that it's actually a misconception, due to protocol, version and CDN differences, hits are very low ~17%. So overhead is not worth it

Comment: @user247077 There are actually more chances that it would be faster because the browser would make parallel requests

Comment: @user247077 It may take extra time, but it will only do so **once**... and likely not at all because there is a ***very*** high chance the client has visited another site using the exact same url.

Comment: @Mooseman: In any case it will do it only once :-). My lib or Google lib, the poitn is whether google can make it 0 (very unlikely, only 17% of time) and with lower cost(unlikely- extra connection to google)

Comment: @user247077 My point is that it's unlikely that a DNS lookup or any connection to Google would even occur because it is cached already. From where does 17% come?

Comment: @Mooseman- 17% (two comments above, sorry no sources right now)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been A/B testing the Google CDN vs. a local copy of jQuery served from my Linode for nearly two years now and logging timing data about how long it takes to move beyond that script reference (cache hits being close to 0). The Google CDN is hands-down the winner, on average, and dramatically so many geographic locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [Google hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) and stop carrying about jquery size.

I am sure every user browser has it in cache already, so its beneficial both for you and user.

Comment: I'd love to see statistics about it

Comment: @Brewal even Stackoverflow is using it ;)

Comment: I know, but there is multiple versions of jQuery. I think it would be great to know the percentage of user having a jquery cached, and what version(s) of jQuery are cached